# OnTriggerEnter Unity c# trigger not registering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to have a bullet item that is tagged with "Bullet" hit a target that this code is attached to. I have Is Trigger ticked on the bullet. Collision is working on the target as I can hit into it with the player. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Bullet"))
    {
        Debug.Log ("Hit!");
        Destroy(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is easier to help with actual errors. What have you tried so far? Your code sample is incomplete, please check [MCVE]

Comment: Are you sure your **Collider** is set as _Trigger_? Also are you sure your bullet isn't too fast and goes through your player from one frame to another?

Comment: I would use a ballistics library or simple raycasts instead depending on use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bullet (collision detection type - `discrete`) travelling fast will go through a static wall (simply a box collider OR a mesh collider. Its not a dynamic object as there's no rigidbody) without registering OnTriggerEnter.

**Continuous Collision Detection :** To solve this issue we can change the collision detection type to `continuous` for the bullet. Bullet collision detection will become `continuous` and will not miss the wall even at fast speed.

[image: Collision Detection Setting in RigidBody component]

**Continuous Dynamic Collision Detection :** Also if we want the bullet to hit a dynamic object(having rigidBody,eg. moving enemy character), then we need to set both of these object to `Continuous` collision detection and at least one of these objects to `Continuous Dynamic` collision detection.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have saved me a lot of fumbling around blindly :)

Comment: your welcome! please accept as answer to let others know its the right solution.

Comment: Continuous collision detection does not work with trigger colliders.